# if CheckBox is check doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want simply check checkbox in WPF project, but I must do something wrong.

Here is XAML code

```
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="287,83,0,0"
      VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="BoxCheck"/>
```

And C# Code

```
if(BoxCheck.Checked) Textbox.Text += " Work?";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`IsChecked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked(v=vs.110).aspx) property. However you'd need to specify what should happen when the checkbox is in [indeterminate state](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked(v=vs.110).aspx)  (when the value of `IsChecked` property is set to null). So I suggest that you use the [Null Coalescing Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) like this:

```
if (BoxCheck.IsChecked ?? false)
{
    Textbox.Text += " Work?";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong property. What you're looking for is `BoxCheck.IsChecked`. The `Checked` property is an `Event` which is occurs when the `CheckBox` is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Yea you right. Thanks.
But I must use:

```
if((bool)BoxCheck.Checked) Textbox.Text += " Work?";
```

Because in this case is type ***bool?***
so you must add (bool) to condition.

Via.
[Cast from bool? to bool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/how-to-safely-cast-from-bool-to-bool)